# Which toolkit should I use to make an easily editable and modern looking GUI for existing c++ code?

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am starting a new small project where the graphic interface and a bit of juggling data too and fro is missing, but the complex and time-critial parts of the code exist and are written in c/c++. Previously I've used the win32 api, MFC to do the graphics, but I want something a bit more modern looking and newer and something that is a bit simpler to maintain and update. I should probably mention that I also want to try out and learn something new...

A few years ago I tried integrating c++ components to c# using pinvoke. It turned out quite messy. But that was a long time ago...

Any tips? What should I use?

Prerequisites: Windows (XP or 7) and VS 2005, 2008 or 2010. Eclipse should also work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try QT or wxWidgets that are both good C++ GUI toolkits.
If you don't have much entry point in the c++ code yuo could wrap them in few C# classes and use WPF or windows form (.NET 4 or 2). Anyway this requires to "mix managed and unmanaged code".

Comment: yes both qt and wxWidgets are opensource. i suggest you QT: it has an LGPL license and is really good looking and cross platform

Comment: You need Windows for C#, but apart from that .NET and Visual Studio Express are free.

Comment: The budget is for additional software. I already have VS 2005, 2008 & 2010.

Comment: This answer contains the basic options. If you are developing in Visual Studio already, C# might be a nice option. I often use Interop with an unmanaged c/c++ dll when I need and keep the rest in C#. It works really well and development is fast, at least for me.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tried it myself in a long time, but from what I hear .NET integration with managed/native is pretty good these days:

- requires no extra tinkering or dependencies; when the project is in Visual Studio, you're ready to roll,
- pretty straight-forward GUI coding,
- simple to maintain,
- any language of your pick for the GUI: C#, F#, J#, managed C++ [and more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages) (comes in handy when you want to try something new).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend integration between C# and C++ using C++/CLI aka Managed C++. With the main project being C++/CLI using C# classes for visually designed GUI. No pinvoke should be necessary. All code (GUI and library part) could even be contained in a single executable (but dependent on the presence of .Net).

If the budget was not an obstacle (around 150$ in this case) I would also mention C++Builder -  visual GUI design and native executable ( no .Net dependency)

Comment: How is the performance of managed c++/CLI comparing to standard c++? Slow? the same?

Comment: When using the unmanaged C++ subset it is the same as the standard C++, calling to the managed part may involve some penalty but it should not be noticeable in the case of GUI.

Comment: How do you connect the c# with the c++? I can't find any way except using dllImport and such. Becomes real slow...

Comment: Create a new project as one from Visual C++/CLR group. After that you can add references to DLL libraries with C# code in the usual way. Intellisense will know C++ syntax wrappers around imported C# classes. Similarly you can add references to C++/CLR class libraries in a C# project.

Answer (score 1):

You write the GUI using QT, and link in your existing C++ code.